# Import from S3 to MySQL RDS and create tables for aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I am new to aws rds. Now I am trying to import several csv files to MySQL RDS with Data Pipeline service. I chose the so-called Load S3 data into RDS MySQL table template. But the parameters is where I have a headache.

My data is in my S3://username/upload folder. The files names:  aisles.csv, departments.csv, orders.csv, products.csv, order_products__train.csv. My RDS is newly created so no tables there. So how to write the parameters to create a separate a table named after each file name(extension excluded) for each of my 5 files? Thanks you.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a work around for this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @ Manas Jani https://medium.com/algoandcoding/little-course-project-extraction-transformation-and-loading-b9209a3538be